# copy a column with a variable start

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I have:

[image]

And my probleme is simple: I want to copy all rows Under "Maintenance" (C8) in worksheet 2, BUT I want it to work even if we delete some rows above "Maintenance" (C8).

for example:

[image]

because it changes the start of the copy. (from 8 to end before, and 5 to end after)

Here is my code :

```html
n = 8 
j = 2 
Sheets("1").Select 
Do While Cells(n, 1) <> "x" 
   If Cells(n, 1) <> "x" Then 
    Sheets("2").Cells(j, 2) = Sheets("1").Cells(n, 2) 
    Sheets("2").Cells(j, 3) = Sheets("1").Cells(n, 3) 
    j = j + 1 
   End If 
 n = n + 1 
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Range.Find()` method to find where "Maintenance" starts, then pull the data below it until whatever condition defines the end of that data (empty cells or a new category name)

For OP's code:

```
n = Sheets("1").UsedRange.Find("Maintenance",LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
```

Comment: here is my code :

n = 8 
j = 2 
Sheets("1").Select                
      Do While Cells(n, 1) <> "x"                 
             If Cells(n, 1) <> "x" Then                 
        Sheets("2").Cells(j, 2) = Sheets("1").Cells(n, 2)                            Sheets("2").Cells(j, 3) = Sheets("1").Cells(n, 3)                        
    j = j + 1
                    End If 
                        n = n + 1
                Loop

Comment: @babou please append this code to your question, not as a comment on my answer

Comment: done, didnt know it will do that ahah

so i just need to change n variable with Range.Find() 

and my copy end with it find a "x" in column A